# I'm trying to make a computer to read a short text

Tags: c#

I have a text "hello world" in Windows Forms application C#. When the form opens, it should say hello world in voice by computer is it easy to suggest?

I don't have any idea so that I am unable to write a code here.

like

```
label1.text.read();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

// Configure the audio output. 
synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

// Speak a string.
synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");
```